# Is there an async validate lib for F#?

Tags: f#

I'm using asyncResult a lot in my code but it'll exit at the first error:

```
asyncResult {

    let! a = allGood()
    let! b = thisReturnsError()
    let! c = neverExecuted()
}
```

but sometimes I want to execute ALL functions and sum up the errors:

```
validation {
    let! a = doSomething()
    and! b = doSomethingElse()
    and! c = andAnotherThing()
}
```

and then I either get an Ok, or a Error with a list of errors.

This is great, but I would like to be able to do both!

```
asyncValidation {
    let! a = doSomethingAsync()
    and! b = doSomethingElseAsync()
    and! c = andAnotherThingAsync()
}
```

Is there a lib doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just threw this together, but I think it works:

```ml
type Validation<'a, 'err> = Result<'a, List<'err>>

type AsyncValidation<'a, 'err> = Async<Validation<'a, 'err>>

module AsyncValidation =

    let bind (f : _ -> AsyncValidation<_, _>) (av : AsyncValidation<_, _>) : AsyncValidation<_, _> =
        async {
            match! av with
                | Ok a -> return! (f a)
                | Error errs -> return Error errs
        }

    let ok a : AsyncValidation<_, _> =
        async { return Ok a }

    let zip (av1 : AsyncValidation<_, _>) (av2 : AsyncValidation<_, _>) : AsyncValidation<_, _> =
        async {
            let! v1 = av1
            let! v2 = av2
            match v1, v2 with
                | Ok a1, Ok a2 -> return Ok (a1, a2)
                | Error errs, Ok _
                | Ok _, Error errs -> return Error errs
                | Error errs1, Error errs2 -> return Error (errs1 @ errs2)
        }

type AsyncValidationBuilder() =
    member _.Bind(av, f) = AsyncValidation.bind f av
    member _.Return(a) = AsyncValidation.ok a
    member _.MergeSources(av1, av2) = AsyncValidation.zip av1 av2

let asyncValidation = AsyncValidationBuilder()
```

Test code:

```ml
let doSomethingAsync () = async { return Ok 1 }
let doSomethingElseAsync () = async { return Error ["hello"] }
let andAnotherThingAsync () = async { return Error ["world"] }
let test =
    asyncValidation {
        let! a = doSomethingAsync ()
        and! b = doSomethingElseAsync ()
        and! c = andAnotherThingAsync ()
        return a + b + c
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously
printfn "%A" test   // Error ["hello"; "world"]
```

Comment: @brian_berns: I have posted a followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790892/how-to-modify-this-ce-to-return-error-as-a-single-item-vs-a-list-in-f

Answer (score 4):

With [F#+](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus) you can combine applicatives by using `Compose`:

```
#r @"nuget: FSharpPlus"

open FSharpPlus
open FSharpPlus.Data

// Generic applicative CE. At the moment not included in the library.
type ApplicativeBuilder<'a>() =
    inherit MonadFxStrictBuilder<'a>()
    member inline _.BindReturn(x, f) = map f x
let applicative<'t> = ApplicativeBuilder<'t> ()


let allGoodAsync () : Async<Validation<string, int>> = async { printfn "first success"; return Success 1 }
let thisResturnsErrorAsync () : Async<Validation<string, int>> = async { return Failure "thisReturnsError" }
let neverExecutedAsync () : Async<Validation<string, int>> = async { printfn "actually executed"; return Success 3 }

let x: Async<Validation<string, _>> =
    applicative {
        let! (a: int) = allGoodAsync () |> Compose
        and! (b: int) = thisResturnsErrorAsync () |> Compose
        and! (c: int) = neverExecutedAsync () |> Compose
        return a + b + c
        }
    |> Compose.run
let y = Async.RunSynchronously x
```

results in

```
> 
first success
actually executed
val y: Validation<string,int> = Failure "thisReturnsError"
```

**UPDATE**

Revisiting this answer, this could be further simplified as follow:

```
type ApplicativeBuilder2<'a>() =
    inherit Builder<'a>()
    member inline _.BindReturn(x, f) = map f x
    member inline _.Source x = Compose x
    member inline _.Run x = Compose.run x
let applicative2<'t> = ApplicativeBuilder2<'t> ()
```

So you don't need to mess with `Compose` :

```
let x: Async<Validation<string, _>> =
    applicative2 {
        let! (a: int) = allGoodAsync ()
        and! (b: int) = thisResturnsErrorAsync ()
        and! (c: int) = neverExecutedAsync ()
        return a + b + c
        }
```

and since the F# type inference bug mentioned in the comments still wasn't fixed I can say now that both `applicative` and `applicative2`   will be definitely included in next version of F#+.

Comment: thanks for this. This is going to be very useful. I have taken Brian's answer as the solution because it provides me an easy solution where I don't have to use the Compose calls, but I can see your answer will be useful in a few other contexts. WIll this be eventually included in F#+?

Comment: @Gus: I don't think this addresses the request "to execute ALL functions and sum up the errors". In applicative usage (i.e. using `and!` instead of `let!`), we always want `neverExecutedAsync` to be called, even when `thisResturnsErrorAsync` fails.

Comment: @Thomas no worries I just intended to show another solution. As you said it might be useful in other scenarios.

@BrianBerns that's the case here, see the last printing `"actually executed"`  comes from  `neverExecutedAsync `.

Comment: @Thomas Regarding your question about eventually inclusion in F#+ do you mean those 4 lines for the Applicative CE? If so, we have it on hold as it shouldn't be necessary because in theory the `monad` CE should work fine here, but it doesn't because of some type inference errors in the F# compiler awaiting for a fix. Eventually if the fix takes too long we might include it but it's only 4 lines.

Comment: @Gus, ok got it!

Comment: "an easy solution where I don't have to use the Compose calls"  I just did one, see the update.